# Excel formula: If time is greater then 23:30, return 11:30 of the same date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table with information below:

E: Date and time in MM/DD/YY HH:MM format
H: # of Hours
I: Expected completion time in MM/DD/YY HH:MM format

I is E+H and skipping weekend and holidays, the formula is

```
=IFERROR(WORKDAY(E5,H5/24,Holidays!$A$2:$A$37)+MOD(E5,1)+MOD(H5,24)/24,"")
```

But if the result return a time within 00:00 - 09:00, I would like to change the time to 11:30, otherwise, keep it as it is

For example:

If the result is 03/05/19 03:52, then change the time to 03/05/19 11:30

If the result is 03/05/19 22:00, then keep the time as  03/05/19 22:00

The time would keep as 11:30 no matter what the original time is

I was trying this formula but it is not working:

```
=IF(WORKDAY(E5,H5/24,Holidays!$A$2:$A$37)+MOD(E5,1)+MOD(H5,24)/24>WORKDAY(E5,H5/24,Holidays!$A$2:$A$37)+MOD(E5,1)+TIME(23,30,0),WORKDAY(E5,H5/24,Holidays!$A$2:$A$37)+MOD(E5,1)&TIME(11,30,0),WORKDAY(E5,H5/24,Holidays!$A$2:$A$37)+MOD(E5,1)+MOD(H5,24)/24)
```

Could anyone help me on this? Appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try truncating the datetime cell to midnight of that date, and then add 11.5 hours:

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(A1) >= 23, MINUTE(A1) > 30),
    TRUNC(A1) + TIME(11,30,00), A1)
```

I tested this formula and it seems to work.  You may have to play around with the cell formatting of the source data.  The format mask `3/14/12 1:30 PM` seems to work well here.

Answer (score 0):

Raise the time to 11:30:00 if it is less than that. Leave it alone if the time is greater than 11:30:00.

```
=IFERROR(WORKDAY(E5,H5/24,Holidays!$A$2:$A$37)+MAX(TIME(11, 30, 0), MOD(E5,1)+MOD(H5,24)/24),"")
```